# how to read matrix in excel vba?

Tags: vba, excel, matrix, multidimensional-array, markov-chains

I want to read and store values from 4*4 matrix(2 dimensional array) and use it in my further program. I am talking about VBA for Excel. Data is in Excel sheet and I want to read it through VBA. I am new to this, but learning fast. Please help me doing it.

this is my data in sheet

a  2 5 6

b  6 8 7

c  3 6 9

this is what I want to do

a 0 2 7  13

b 0 6 14 21

c 0 3 9  18

I need to read 3*3 matrix from sheet and transform it to cumulative matrix as shown. (add the previous number and go on).

Basically I am simulating a Markov Chain and needs to count how many times a person go through each stage.
    Sub example7()

```
Dim A As Double, B As Double, C As Double, PC(4, 4) As Double, row As Double, maxrwo As Double, col As Double, maxcol As Double

Range("o5").Activate

For i = 1 To 4
For j = 1 To 4
PC(i, j) = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select

Next j

ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Select
Next i

Range("T4") = PC(2, 4)

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: It is quite easy to get a 2 dimensional array from a range to a VBA variable. For example, if `A` is declared to be type `Variant` and the data is in range A1:D4 then the line `A = Range("A1:D4").Value` will transfer the data to `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to process values in a range you don't need to store them in an array first.  You could loop through each cell in the range by using code similar to the below:

```
Sub LoopThroughRange()

Dim currentCell As Range
Dim desiredRange As Range
Dim outputCell As Range
Dim total As Double

Set outputCell = Range("A6")
Set desiredRange = Range("Sheet1!A1:D4")

'This will add the values of each cell in the range and output the total to cell A6
For Each currentCell In desiredRange

   total = total + currentCell.Value

Next currentCell

outputCell.Value = total

End Sub
```